# How to validate only type phone number with js

Tags: javascript, validation, phone-number

How can I `validate`only type number with `javascript`? for example. I want only this pattern to check in my phone number field "`(033) 123-45-67`"

Comment: There are countless examples of this available all over the internet (including here), please search before posting. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+phone+number

Answer (score 4):

Use Regular Expression

```
var regexp = /^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

regexp.test('(033) 123-45-67'); // true
regexp.test('(0331) 123-45-67'); // false
regexp.test('(033 123-45-67'); // false
regexp.test('(033) 123+45-67'); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

You use a regular expression.

```
/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
```

`^` indicates the start of the string, `$` indicates the end of the string, `\d` is shorthand for 0-9, `{n}` means the preceeding must match exactly `n` times, and since parenthesis are special characters you need to escape them as `\(` and `\)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "regular expressions" to match patterns in strings, such as phone numbers. For example, the folowing pattern,

`\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d`

would match the phone number you gave. Each part of the expression is meant to match some part of the given string. In this case, for example, `\d` matches a "digit", and `\(` matches an opening parenthesis. There are also plenty of short-cuts and tricks you can do to make cooler more flexible patterns. Read up on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) on the internet.

P.S. while you are out there learning about regex, you might find [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) useful for testing your sweet patterns!